# QTableWidget Integer

Tags: python, integer, pyqt, qtablewidgetitem

I am trying to insert and display integers in my QTableWidget.  They don't display.  It works if I convert everything to strings, but then I can't sort columns numerically--only lexically (1, 10, 100, etc.).  This is using PyQt.

I've tried some of the suggested solutions, using QTableWidgetItem.setData(someRole,intValue), bu then nothing at all displays.  I've tried, Qt.UserRole, DisplayRole and Edit Role.  (I don't understand why these Roles are needed to display integers, but have just followed the examples).  My specific code is:

```
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData = (Qt.DisplayRole,intValue)
    myTable.setItem(row, column, item)
```

The following code works, but for strings only:

```
    item = QTableWidgetItem(str(intValue))
    myTable.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Also, the suggestions for reading the data back, only show the object location, not the actual data.  Example, using Eric as an interpreter shell:

item.data(Qt.DisplayRole)

Response: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x1f01fa60

or this:

item.data(Qt.EditRole).data()

Response: sip.voidptr object at 0x1e904a80

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were on the right track. Your code doesn't work because you're not calling the `QTableWidgetItem`'s `setData()` function but trying to assign it a value. You have

```
item.setData = (Qt.DisplayRole,intValue)
```

instead of

```
item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,intValue)
```

Also, when reading the data back it's not just the location that's shown but the data itself as a [QVariant](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qvariant.html). You should find that `item.data(Qt.DisplayRole).toString()` will return your data back as a string by converting the `QVariant` (via its `.toString()` method).

Here's a quick working example just to demonstrate:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(101, 1)
        self.table_widget.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.widget_layout)

        for num in xrange(101):
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.EditRole, num)
            self.table_widget.setItem(num, 0, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  widget = Widget()
  widget.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks Gary.  Though I'm still not sure what the Roles have to do with this working correctly.

Comment: @GarryHughes Is it possible give them float?