# how to make a particular column in QTreeWidget integer/Float, such that the user can't enter any alphabets or symbols instead of integers/Floats?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I am making a GUI in PyQt5 which uses QTreeWidget. I want a particular column to be integer only column. The user shouldn't be able to enter any non integer item in it. I saw some methods using QVariant but it doesn't seem to fullfill my requirement.

Here is what I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074035/qtablewidget-integer)!
.But this seems to me like setting the data from the back-end not from the user side.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(478, 320)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 478, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Some other data"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Only Integers"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Text"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).child(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Sub Text"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Here is code and the image. Please let me know what changes should i make in the code to achieve my objective. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to establish a delegate in the second column that has as editor a `QSpinBox`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # ...


class IntegerDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setFrame(False)
        editor.setMinimum(-2147483648)
        editor.setMaximum(2147483647)
        editor.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, editor.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy()
        )
        return editor


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        delegate = IntegerDelegate(self.treeWidget)
        self.treeWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```
class DoubleDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setFrame(False)
        editor.setMinimum(-1.7976931348623157e+308)
        editor.setMaximum(1.7976931348623157e+308)
        editor.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, editor.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy()
        )
        return editor
```

Comment: Can this solution be applied for real numbers too? I looked around for Floatdelegates as well as doubleDelegates.

Comment: @StarRider I have already updated my answer, check if it worked.

Comment: It works like magic. Thank you so much!. I would be happy know from which resource I can learn more about this delegates as there is not  much I could find on google. Thanks once again!

Comment: @StarRider The best information is in the Qt docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html. Although written for C++, the logic is maintained for python.