# PyQt5: fill all columns of QTableWidget

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to solve the sorting issue and found this answer:
[QTableWidget Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074035/qtablewidget-integer)

So I borrowed the code, and tried to test and fill multiple columns. However, the second column doesn't get filled for some reason. See below for the code I am using:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(101, 2)
        self.table_widget.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.widget_layout)

        for num in range(101):
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.EditRole, num)
            self.table_widget.setItem(num, 0, item)
            item2 = QTableWidgetItem()
            item2.setData(Qt.EditRole, num)
            self.table_widget.setItem(num, 1, item2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  widget = Widget()
  widget.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Not sure what went wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you enable sorting before adding items to the table. This means that the table is resorted every time a new item is added. If you scroll down to the bottom of the table in your example, you will see that the last row of the second column has a value. So what is happening is that the same cell of the second column is being set every time, due to the constant re-sorting.

In general, it's best to disable sorting whilst populating a table as it is much more efficient (as well as avoiding unexpected results). To fix your example, I would suggest moving the code into a separate method, like this:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(101, 2)
        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.widget_layout)
        self.fillTable()

    def fillTable(self):
        self.table_widget.clearContents()
        self.table_widget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.table_widget.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        for num in range(101):
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.EditRole, num)
            self.table_widget.setItem(num, 0, item)
            item2 = QTableWidgetItem()
            item2.setData(Qt.EditRole, num)
            self.table_widget.setItem(num, 1, item2)
        self.table_widget.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will offer an explanation of what's happening behind the scenes here:

From what I can see after executing the script, everything seems normal. So why is that **column 2** gets items only at the **bottom row**?

See.. the table's size is already set. There's a number of blank rows already pre-allocated on the table.

```
    1    2
  1 _    _
  2 _    _
  3 _    _
  4 _    _
  5 _    _
  6 _    _
  7 _    _
  8 _    _
  9 _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
 99 _    _
100 _    _
```

When the first items are inserted, `num==0`, they do get inserted in both columns:

```
    1    2
  1 0    0    <-- both items are inserted at row 1
  2 _    _
  3 _    _
  4 _    _
  5 _    _
  6 _    _
  7 _    _
  8 _    _
  9 _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
 99 _    _
100 _    _
```

However as sorting is enabled, and, look at this image here:

[image]

This **arrow** indicates that the first column is being sorted by default. When you're going to insert `num==1` at the 2nd row, the first step is to insert it on column 1:

```
    1    2
  1 0    0
  2 1    _  <-- inserting num==1 at column 1
  3 _    _
  4 _    _
  5 _    _
  6 _    _
  7 _    _
  8 _    _
  9 _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
 99 _    _
100 _    _
```

As the `num==1` is inserted at column 1, and the sorting is enabled by default, the column 1 is sorted instantly after it's done:

```
    1    2
  1 1    _   <-- auto sorting is enabled on column 1. Rows are swapped.
  2 0    0
  3 _    _
  4 _    _
  5 _    _
  6 _    _
  7 _    _
  8 _    _
  9 _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
 99 _    _
100 _    _
```

And now, we will insert `num==1` on the next column:

```
    1    2
  1 1    _
  2 0    1    <-- See here? The value 0 was overwritten
  3 _    _
  4 _    _
  5 _    _
  6 _    _
  7 _    _
  8 _    _
  9 _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
  . _    _
 99 _    _
100 _    _
```

This pattern repeats until we reach the bottom of the rows:

```
    1    2
  1 100  _
  2 99   _
  3 98   _
  4 97   _
  5 96   _
  6 96   _
  7 95   _
  8 94   _
  9 93   _
  . ..   _
  . ..   _
  . ..   _
 99  1   _
100  0   100
```

So, everything is working "exactly as planned". Not by you maybe, but to PyQt5, this is what it though you wanted to do when you enabled column sorting **before** inserting items on the table.

Comment: A small note: it's not about PyQt, it's just Qt. No matter what bindings are used, they rely on the behavior of the "base" library.